# Battlemind using at-will ability for opportunity attacks

Tags: dnd-4e, opportunity-attack, battlemind

I'm playing a Level 4 Half-Elf Harrier Battlemind. I'm pretty happy with him all up, tanky, hard to hit, doesn't do a huge amount of damage, but can fairly reliably hit his targets.

My biggest stumbling block, is that my opportunity attacks feel pretty much useless, because my melee basic attack only has a +8 to hit bonus and the damage is 1d8+4, whereas my at-will Battlemind abilities have a +11 to hit bonus and are generally 1d8+6 damage. I've had a bit of a look but can't find anything that would allow me to use one of my Battlemind abilities for the opportunity attack. They are all at-will standard actions. I have Shade Strike, Iron Fist, and World Slipping Advance.

To be clear, this would only be useful when enemies are moving past me to try and attack my allies, if they are committing an attack on my allies, it'd be more efficient and damaging to use Mind Spike, because I have Bolstering Spike, so I get temporary hit points when I use it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few option to get a decent opportunity attack as a Battlemind.

The easiest is to get the Level 1 At-Will Twisted Eye<sup>[[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=2621)]</sup> which has:

> **Augment 1
>
>   Special:** When making an opportunity attack, you can use this power in place of a melee 
>   basic attack.

Another option is the feat Melee Training (Constitution)<sup>[[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=1016)]</sup>, which allows you to use your Constitution mod instead of Strength for attack rolls, and 1/2 your Constitution modifier for damage rolls when making basic attacks.

The best option will be having your Half-Elf Dilettante be Eldritch Strike.<sup>[[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=7402)]</sup> This is a Warlock power that can be used in place of a melee basic attack, and can slide 1. This power uses your Constitution modifier for both the attack and damage rolls. In order to use this power as an at-will power you will have to wait until Level 11 when you can get the feat Versatile Master<sup>[[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=1082)]</sup>, which allows you to use you Dilettante power at-will instead of 1/Encounter

Your best option is probably to take either Melee Training or Twisted Eye in Heroic, then when you hit paragon get Versatile Master. The choice between Melee Training and Twisted Eye depends on a few things. If you are being granted extra basic attacks from your allies you probably want Melee Training, since that works for all melee basic attacks and not just opportunity attacks. On the other hand if your build is very feat starved Twisted Eye might be a better option to go with.

Comment: +1, Good answer. Worth nothing that Eldritch Strike can be used on an opportunity attack even if it's an encounter power. Only once per encounter though, of course.